# Not able to add proxy to react.js app, how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have been trying for a long time now, I tried all the solutions on the internet but it is not working.
I added "proxy":"http://localhost/5000" to my package.json file but it is not being recognised at all it feels.

Whenever I am trying to fetch("/") it is sending a request to localhost:3000 which is the port for my react app and not the server.
Please help me fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your fetch request API url to give the complete hostname since

fetch('http://localhost:5000/')